# How do I delete directory and file, if .picasa.ini is the only file in the directory?

Tags: find, rm

I want to start from a root directory and recurse through the tree. I want to delete the directory and file if there is only one file in the directory called .picasa.ini

It seems like the "find" command can do a lot of complex searches, but I don't know if can perform actions based on this type of condition.

I am using a Windows machine, but have access to cygwin which provides many command line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done with a single `find` command, but it can certainly be done with a simple bash script. I've just tested this on Cygwin and it works as intended. You'll want to change `ROOT_DIR` to be the root of whatever filesystem you want to perform this search on (for example `/cygdrive/d/` to search the D drive).

The general idea is this: find all files named `.picasa.ini` in the tree. For each one, look in its directory to see if there are any other files. If there aren't, remove the directory.  (The double quotes around `$dir` will remove directories that contain spaces.) Otherwise move on.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_DIR=/

find "$ROOT_DIR" -type f -name '.picasa.ini' | while read file; do
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    filecount=$(ls -1A "$dir" | wc -l)
    if (( filecount == 1 )); then
            rm -rv "$dir"
    fi
done
```